# check for every div if the previous div isn't having the same class attribute

Tags: javascript, css

So my code looks like this: (random generated)

```
<div class="class1"> </div>
<div class="class2"> </div>
<div class="class1"> </div>
<div class="class1"> </div>
<div class="class2"> </div>
<div class="class1"> </div>
<div class="class1"> </div>
<div class="class1"> </div>
<div class="class2"> </div>
```

And now i want to check for every single div if the previous div isn't having the same class attribute

I want to achiev something like this:

```
<div class="class1"> </div> <!-- first div: nothing happens-->
<div class="class2"> </div> <!-- previous div has other class: margin-top:10px;-->
<div class="class1"> </div> <!-- previous div has other class: margin-top:10px;-->
<div class="class1"> </div> <!-- same class: nothing happens-->
<div class="class2"> </div> <!-- previous div has other class: margin-top:10px;-->
<div class="class1"> </div> <!-- previous div has other class: margin-top:10px;-->
<div class="class1"> </div> <!-- same class: nothing happens-->
<div class="class1"> </div> <!-- same class: nothing happens-->
<div class="class2"> </div> <!-- previous div has other class: margin-top:10px;-->
```

I think i need to loop every single div and check if the previous div has the same class, or something similar

I really hope it is better to understand now. :)

Comment: The HTML code should be added exactly as it is, not just a pseudo-code. Explain with example _div's with the same classes are among themselves_. Also, add your attempts to solve the problem. Is [tag:PHP] necessary here?

Comment: What do you want to do if there are duplicate classes? Apply a style, do something with jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean by "among themselves"?

Comment: @Tushar Okay i tried to explain it better now. Its very hard to descrbe it for me, sorry.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody DeWoody DeWoody I edited the Question, maybe its easier to understand now.

Comment: @MattWay Way I mean i want to check if two divs are 
one behind the other in the code

Comment: @Tushar exactly, that was the word i was looking for

Comment: Only two? What about more than two in a row; what happens then?

Comment: @fauxserious you're right. I think i know now what im looking for. Edited the question aggain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//iterate over the divs
$('div[class^="class"]').each(function(){
    //get the previous div with correct class
    var prev = $(this).prev('div[class^="class"]');
    //if there's a previous element and it doesn't match the class
    if(prev.length > 0 && !$(this).hasClass(prev.prop('class'))){
        //add the margin
        $(this).css('margin-top', '10px');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the below should work. Hold reference to the previous class. Iterate all divs starting with `^=`, check if the prev class matches the class of the element we're looping, then apply our margin top. Finally, set the previous class to the current element's class for comparison on the next iteration.

```
var prev_class;

$('div[class^="class"]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if(prev_class == $this.prop('class')){
        $this.css('margin-top', '10px');
    }

    prev_class = $this.prop('class');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery's next() and prev() and hasClass(), you could see class differences:

```js
$("div").on("click", function()
{
  alert($(this).attr("class"));
  alert($(this).next().attr("class"));
  alert($(this).prev().attr("class"));
  alert($(this).next().hasClass("class1"));
  alert($(this).prev().hasClass("class1"));
});
```

```css
.class1
{
  width:100%;
  height:3rem;
  background:blue;
}
.class2
{
  width:100%;
  height:3rem;
  background:green;
}
.class3
{
  width:100%;
  height:3rem;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class2"></div>
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class3"></div>
```

Comment: you can further iterate over elements using the each() function as shown by @Ohgodwhy. Keep in mind next and prev refer to the current item silbings.